# How to add css class and css module on one item?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, in React I write my css in css modules. However, I also use the font-awesome library which uses normal css.

So my question is there is a way to use a normal css and css module on the same selector?

`<i className={classes.icon} + "far fa-user" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to ES6 syntax, you can write it like this:

```
<i className={`${classes.icon} far fa-user`} />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you completely understand how React works, you will be putting it this way:

```js
<i className={classes.icon + " far fa-user"} />
```

The `classes.icon` will be the `className` string and along with it, you have to add other classes.